# How to create odds ratio and 95 % CI plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have estimates of odds ratio with corresponding 95% CI of six pollutants overs 4 lag periods. How can I create a vertical plot similar to the attached figure in R? The figure below was created  in SPSS. 
Sample data that produced the figure is the following:

```
lag pollut  or  lcl ucl
0   CO  0.97    0.90    1.06
0   PM10    1.00    0.91    1.09
0   NO  0.97    0.92    1.02
0   NO2 1.01    0.89    1.15
0   SO2 0.97    0.85    1.11
0   Ozone   1.00    0.87    1.15
1   CO  1.03    0.95    1.10
1   PM10    0.93    0.86    1.01
1   NO  1.01    0.97    1.06
1   NO2 1.08    0.97    1.20
1   SO2 0.94    0.84    1.04
1   Ozone   0.94    0.84    1.04
2   CO  1.09    1.02    1.16
2   PM10    1.04    0.96    1.13
2   NO  1.04    1.00    1.08
2   NO2 1.07    0.96    1.18
2   SO2 1.05    0.95    1.17
2   Ozone   0.93    0.84    1.03
3   CO  0.98    0.91    1.06
3   PM10    1.14    1.05    1.24
3   NO  0.99    0.95    1.04
3   NO2 1.01    0.91    1.12
3   SO2 1.11    1.00    1.23
3   Ozone   1.00    0.90    1.11
```

[image: Odds ratio and 95 % CI plot created in SPSS]

Comment: There is code on how to create a plot with 95%CI here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Mark_W._Miller  I do not know whether that code will help with your data set.

Comment: Odds ratios really should be on a logarithmic scale (i.e., the  vertical distance between 0.5 and 1 should be the same distance as between 1 and 2 because both are a doubling of the odds).  ggplot2 can do this with `scale_y_log10()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your data are in `datf`...

I'd sort it first into just what you want order wise.

```
datf <- datf[order(datf$pollut, datf$lag), ]
```

You want a space before and after every lab grouping so I'd add some extra rows in that are NA.  That makes it easier because then you'll automatically have blanks in your plot calls.

```
datfPlusNA <- lapply(split(datf, datf$pollut), function(x) rbind(NA, x, NA))
datf <- do.call(rbind, datfPlusNA)
```

Now that you have your data.frame sorted and with the extra NAs the plotting is easy.

```
nr <- nrow(datf)  # find out how many rows all together
with(datf, {# this allows entering your commands more succinctly
    # first you could set up the plot so you can select the order of drawing
    plot(1:nr, or, ylim = c(0.8, 1.3), type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', xlab = '', ylab = 'Odds Ratio and 95% CI', frame.plot = TRUE, panel.first = grid(nx = NA, ny = NULL))
    # arrows(1:nr, lcl, 1:nr, ucl, length = 0.02, angle = 90, code = 3, col = factor(lag)) 
    # you could use arrows above but you don't want ends so segments is easier
    segments(1:nr, lcl, 1:nr, ucl, col = factor(lag))
    # add your points
    points(1:nr, or, pch = 19, cex = 0.6)
    xLabels <- na.omit(unique(pollut))
    axis(1, seq(4, 34, by = 6) - 0.5, xLabels)
})
abline(h = 1.0)
```

There are packages that make this kind of thing easier but if you can do it like this you can start doing any graphs that you can imagine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks John. The ucl arrow is missing and I have added "arrows(1:nr, or, 1:nr, ucl)". The code created beautiful plot.  It would be perfect with (1) a reference horizontal line  at 1 (2) smaller arrow heads.

Comment: Arrow heads or extra terminating lines on confidence intervals, or any error bar, are generally considered a no no there days.  It's because it makes the end of the bar more special than it really is... you do expect data after that, you're just going to interpret it differently.

Comment: You should really read the help on arrows (the ones I have in there now look good).

Comment: horizontal line added and horizontal grid lines... vertical grid lines are useless in this plot

Comment: Thanks again. I have now beautiful figures and above all elegant codes that I could use in future. I also like both options (yours and that of Largh) that would allow flexibility.

Comment: @user1754610: Flexibility is probably the main reason to switch over to R for scientists who are not statisticians. Anything you can do with SPSS can also be done with R. As John said, you could produce these plots in several different ways. His suggestion is the most flexible, while Hardley's is probably the "laziest" option yet producing good looking graphics.

Comment: segments(1:nr, or, 1:nr, ucl, col = cols[lag+1]) gives me the following error: "Error in lag + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator", while the same data.frame works with Largh's code.

Comment: You made Lag a factor, probably trying the other code.  You could just leave it a factor leave, of the generation of the cols variable, and just stick it where I'm using an index of colours.  That would work.  In fact, I've decided to just edit it to leave that bit out so factor, numbers, whatver, it will work.

Answer (score 11):

You can also do this with ggplot2. The code is somewhat shorter:

```
 dat <- read.table("clipboard", header = T)
 dat$lag <- paste0("L", dat$lag)

 library(ggplot2)

 ggplot(dat, aes(x = pollut, y = or, ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl)) + geom_pointrange(aes(col = factor(lag)), position=position_dodge(width=0.30)) + 
 ylab("Odds ratio & 95% CI") + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1)) + scale_color_discrete(name = "Lag") + xlab("")
```

[image]

EDIT: Here is a version is closer to the SPSS figure:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = pollut, y = or, ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl)) + geom_linerange(aes(col = factor(lag)), position=position_dodge(width=0.30)) +
geom_point(aes(shape = factor(lag)), position=position_dodge(width=0.30)) + ylab("Odds ratio & 95% CI") + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1)) + xlab("")
```

Comment: Thanks Largh. The two codes produced what I have really wanted to have.

Comment: +1 though I would use a `+scale_y_log10()` since its an odds ratio