# Modiffy axes in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used the following code based on a previous post  [How to create odds ratio and 95 % CI plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386177/how-to-create-odds-ratio-and-95-ci-plot-in-rto) to produce the figure posted below. I would like to:
1) Make x and y axes as well as the legends bold
2) Increase the thickness of the lines

How can I do that in ggplot?

```
ggplot(alln, aes(x = apoll2, y = increase, ymin = l95, ymax = u95)) + geom_pointrange(aes(col = factor(marker)), position=position_dodge(width=0.50)) + 
    ylab("Percent increase & 95% CI") + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) + scale_color_discrete(name = "Marker") + xlab("")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change axis and legend appearance you should add `theme()` to your plot.

```
+ theme(axis.text=element_text(face="bold"),
        legend.text=element_text(face="bold"))
```

To make line wider add s`ize=1.5` inside the `geom_pointrange()` call.